# position of cursor editText - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor

I'm using editText in my app, y XML to set format to them, all is ok but, the EditText cursor is almost out from the editText, I want set other position, suppose this is an EditText
--> (|          ) with its cursor, I want to put the cursor like this --->( |         ).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `android:gravity="center"` on your `EditText` definition, in your layout.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

use `Edittext.setSelection(int index)`